# Potree profile tool clip boxes not visible

Tags: javascript

I adjusted the `viewer.js` example from the Potree project to my own needs. I however find that the clipboxes for the Profile tool are not working anymore. When I start the profile tool I am able to draw the spheres, but no matter what clip mode I use (disabled, clip outside, clip inside) the entire Pointcloud remains visible. I have no idea where to start with the problem, as very little code in `viewer.js` seems to be related to the ProfileTool specifically. Is there something in the material that needs to be set in order for clipping to work? Should the update methods be called in certain order?

Code:

```html
 <button class="shortcut button btn" ng-click="tools.profile({ width: potree.pointcloud.boundingSphere.radius / 100})" tooltip-placement="right" uib-tooltip="Height Profiles">
```

```js
module.controller('PCToolsController', function($rootScope) {
    this.profile = function(options) {
        return $rootScope.$broadcast('profile:start', options);
    };
});
```

And in the update function (called before every render):

```js
controls.update();

controls.profiles.forEach(function(profile) {
    // Clear the clip boxes
    ClipBoxes.length = 0;

    profile.boxes.forEach(function(box) {
        box.updateMatrixWorld();
        var boxInverse = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(box.matrixWorld);
        ClipBoxes.push(boxInverse);
    });
});

controls.render();
```

The `ClipBoxes` are the array of clipboxes in the material, when I enter `pointcloud.material.clipBoxes` I can see the array being filled.

*I know that this may be a little undescriptive, but I don't think sharing thousands of lines of viewer code in a JSFiddle will be of any help, and if I break down the issue by starting from the `viewer.js` as basis, I know that it will work, as the example works. I am therefore not so much looking into a final answer, but rather a direction too look in. Of course if it is beneficial of finding the definite answer I'd be willing to share more info.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to use `material.setClipBoxes(clipBoxes)` rather than updating the array of clipboxes.